# How to compose a key to get an environment.ts value inside a *ngFor? I'm searching for keys of the form 'environment.{{region}}_couche_url' inside it

Tags: html, angular, ngfor

I have currently this piece of HTML that is too much duplicated.

```html
<!-- Carte de la Métropole -->
<div>
  <app-carte [nom] = "(( environment.metropole_nom ))"
     [url_couche] = "(( environment.metropole_couche_url ))"
     [layer_couche] = "(( environment.metropole_couche_layer ))"
     [longitude] = "(( environment.metropole_longitude_initale ))"
     [latitude] = "(( environment.metropole_latitude_initale ))"
     [zoom] = "(( environment.metropole_zoom ))"
     [projection] = "(( environment.metropole_projection ))"></app-carte>
</div>

<!-- Régions d'Outremer -->
<div>
  <!-- Carte de la Guadeloupe -->
  <div>
    <app-carte [nom] = "(( environment.guadeloupe_nom ))"
       [url_couche] = "(( environment.guadeloupe_couche_url ))"
       [layer_couche] = "(( environment.guadeloupe_couche_layer ))"
       [longitude] = "(( environment.guadeloupe_longitude_initale ))"
       [latitude] = "(( environment.guadeloupe_latitude_initale ))"
       [zoom] = "(( environment.guadeloupe_zoom ))"
       [projection] = "(( environment.guadeloupe_projection ))"></app-carte>
  </div>

  <!-- Carte de la Martinique -->
  <div>
    <app-carte [nom] = "(( environment.martinique_nom ))"
       [url_couche]="(( environment.martinique_couche_url ))"
       [layer_couche]="(( environment.martinique_couche_layer ))"
       [longitude] = "(( environment.martinique_longitude_initale ))"
       [latitude] = "(( environment.martinique_latitude_initale ))"
       [zoom] = "(( environment.martinique_zoom ))"
       [projection]= "(( environment.martinique_projection ))"></app-carte>
  </div>

  <!-- Carte de la Guyane -->
  <div>
    <app-carte [nom] = "(( environment.guyane_nom ))"
       [url_couche]="(( environment.guyane_couche_url ))"
       [layer_couche]="(( environment.guyane_couche_layer ))"
       [longitude] = "(( environment.guyane_longitude_initale ))"
       [latitude] = "(( environment.guyane_latitude_initale ))"
       [zoom] = "(( environment.guyane_zoom ))"
       [projection]= "(( environment.guyane_projection ))"></app-carte>
  </div>

  <!-- Carte de La Réunion -->
  <div>
    <app-carte [nom] = "(( environment.la_reunion_nom ))"
       [url_couche]="(( environment.la_reunion_couche_url ))"
       [layer_couche]="(( environment.la_reunion_couche_layer ))"
       [longitude] = "(( environment.la_reunion_longitude_initale ))"
       [latitude] = "(( environment.la_reunion_latitude_initale ))"
       [zoom] = "(( environment.la_reunion_zoom ))"
       [projection]= "(( environment.la_reunion_projection ))"></app-carte>
  </div>

  <!-- Carte de Mayotte -->
  <div>
    <app-carte [nom] = "(( environment.mayotte_nom ))"
       [url_couche] = "(( environment.mayotte_couche_url ))"
       [layer_couche] = "(( environment.mayotte_couche_layer ))"
       [longitude] = "(( environment.mayotte_longitude_initale ))"
       [latitude] = "(( environment.mayotte_latitude_initale ))"
       [zoom] = "(( environment.mayotte_zoom ))"
       [projection] = "(( environment.mayotte_projection ))"></app-carte>
  </div>
</div>
```

After having added a list of the ultramarine regions in its component,

```
export class CarteFranceComponent {
  protected readonly environment= environment;
  protected regions_outremer: string[] = ['guadeloupe', 'martinique', 'guyane', 'la_reunion', 'mayotte']
}
```

I've attempted something like that:

```html
<div *ngFor="let outremer of regions_outremer;">
  <app-carte [nom] = "(( environment.{{outremer}}_nom ))"
     [url_couche] = "(( environment.{{outremer}}_couche_url ))"
     [layer_couche] = "(( environment.{{outremer}}_couche_layer ))"
     [longitude] = "(( environment.{{outremer}}_longitude_initale ))"
     [latitude] = "(( environment.{{outremer}}_latitude_initale ))"
     [zoom] = "(( environment.{{outremer}}_zoom ))"
     [projection] = "(( environment.{{outremer}}_projection ))"></app-carte>
</div>
```

but those aren't recognized statements.

How should I write my `*ngFor` directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the key of an object like `environment.guyane_nom` as well as `environment['guyane_nom']`

So you can tweak the your selector a bit using the template literals with the second way of accessing the property of an object.

So your `ngFor` template can be modified as below and it should work.

```
<div *ngFor="let outremer of regions_outremer;">
  <app-carte
    [nom]="environment[`${outremer}_nom`]"
    [url_couche]="environment[`${outremer}_couche_url`]"
    [layer_couche]="environment[`${outremer}_couche_layer`]"
    [longitude]="environment[`${outremer}_longitude_initale`]"
    [latitude]="environment[`${outremer}_latitude_initale`]"
    [zoom]="environment[`${outremer}_zoom`]"
    [projection]="environment[`${outremer}_projection`]"
  >
  </app-carte>
</div>
```

---

Edit from Marc Le Bihan:

```html
    <app-carte [nom]="(( environment[outremer + '_nom'] ))"
       [url_couche] = "(( environment[outremer + '_couche_url'] ))"
       [layer_couche] = "(( environment[outremer + '_couche_layer'] ))"
       [longitude] = "(( environment[outremer + '_longitude_initale'] ))"
       [latitude] = "(( environment[outremer + '_latitude_initale'] ))"
       [zoom] = "(( environment[outremer + '_zoom'] ))"
       [projection] = "(( environment[outremer + '_projection'] ))">
    </app-carte>
```

is the form that eventually works.
I write it in your reply because you were at a centimeter of the solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No it doesn't. I've pasted your `[nom]="environment.[`${outremer}_nom`]"` but it responds: unexpected token $, and unresolved variable or type _nom. (And I have the backticks)

Comment: @MarcLeBihan oops, there is a typo in my code. Its not environment.[`${outremer}_nom`], instead it should be environment[`${outremer}_nom`] , the additional dot is not needed between the object and the key.

Comment: Sorry, it still not working. Either `[nom]="environment[\`${outremer}_nom\`]"` or `[nom]="environment[${outremer}_nom]"` are refused. For the same error messages. `(( environment[outremer + '_nom'] ))` or `environment[outremer + '_nom']` look accepted, but I have to see if they are extracting what I willing.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan Technically speaking, environment[`${outremer}_nom`] this should work. Can you try checking whats displayed in ui if you try to print it inside the html component like {{ environment[`${outremer}_nom`] }}? Are you getting the correct value in the screen if you print it like this inside the template?

Answer (score 0):

Would say your current `environment` structure makes it complex.

You should work with the structure below to avoid complexity:

```
{
  guadeloupe: {
    nom: 'guadeloupe_nom',
  },
  martinique: {
    nom: 'martinique_nom',
  },
  guyane: {
    nom: 'guyane_nom',
  },
  la_reunion: {
    nom: 'la_reunion_nom',
  },
  mayotte: {
    nom: 'mayotte_nom',
  },
}
```

Transform the existing `environment` to the new structure with:

1. Iterate each value from `regions_outcomer`.
2. Create an object with the `outremer` as key.
3. Get the entry (key-value pair) in the `environment` that should fall under the same group (require the key to start with `outremer` key) and make it a sub-object.
4. This will result in an array of objects. Combine all objects into single object.

```
protected readonly environment: { [key: string]: { [key: string]: any } } =
  Object.assign(
    {},
    ...this.regions_outremer.map((outremer) => {
      let keys = Object.keys(environment).filter((y) =>
        y.startsWith(outremer)
      );

      let newObj: any = {};
      newObj[outremer] = Object.entries(environment)
        .filter((kvp) => keys.indexOf(kvp[0]) > -1)
        .reduce((acc: any, cur: [string, any]) => {
          acc[cur[0].split(`${outremer}_`)[1]] = cur[1];

          return acc;
        }, {} as { [key: string]: any });

      return newObj;
    })
  );
```

For the view, you need to iterate the `environment` properties via `KeyValuePipe`.

```
<div *ngFor="let outremer of environment | keyvalue;">
  <app-carte [nom]="outremer.value.nom"
    [url_couche]="outremer.value.couche_url"
    [layer_couche] ="outremer.value.couche_layer"
    [longitude]="outremer.value.longitude_initale"
    [latitude]="outremer.value.latitude_initale"
    [zoom]="outremer.value.zoom "
    [projection] = "outremer.value.projection"
      
  ></app-carte>
</div>
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-af97rq?file=src%2Fmain.ts)